# MongoDB CurrentOp number in Lock time seems incorrect

Tags: mongodb

I'm checking the status of a long running query on my MongoDB instance. The operation has been running for 1514 seconds. I'm trying to comprehend this output, but the numbers `secs_running`, `timelockedMicros`, `timeAcquiringMicros` are very confusing.

From the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/current-op/), secs_running is the time elapsed since the start of the operation, 1514 seconds in this case. However `timeAcquiringMicros` seems to suggest that the operation has been waiting for the read lock for the entire 1514 seconds, which is obviously incorrect because it has yielded 196762 records so far and has locked for 825 seconds according to `timeLockedMicros`.

Is this a bug in the currentOp() function in MongoDB? I'm using version 2.4.3

```
{
"inprog" : [
    {
        "opid" : 1439744,
        "active" : true,
        "secs_running" : 1514,
        "op" : "getmore",
        "ns" : <namespace>,
        "query" : <query>,
        "client" : "127.0.0.1:50735",
        "desc" : "conn485",
        "threadId" : "0x14f004000",
        "connectionId" : 485,
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "numYields" : 196762,
        "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(825186242),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1514482551),
                "w" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: The operation is a find() query. I've written a script and looping over the records to perform a data migration. The loop uses cursor.next(). For each next, there's a write to a new collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the issue you are seeing is a bug. It is currently marked as closed and fixed in the development branch. You could test by [installing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) 2.5.5 on a test instance and seeing for yourself if required.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10361